# the implied subject of "looking down into a valley"

Tags: participles

> Human beings like a prospect from which they can survey a landscape, and at the same time they enjoy a sense of refuge. A cave on the side of a mountain, a child’s tree house, and the king’s castle are situations with appeal. Protection afforded by an overhang of some sort (trees, cliff face, roof) is preferred, along with a sense of being “safe” from observation or attack from behind. The most attractive landscapes tend to combine some of these elements, in pictures as much as in reality. In fact, most landscape representation in the history of painting places the **implied viewer** at **some desirable vantage point** — a cliff edge, perhaps, typically ***looking down into a valley***.

Q. I was wondering what would be ***looking down into a valley***. Would the implied subject of "looking down ~" be the "implied viewer" or the "vantage point", which rephrased as a cliff edge in this sentence?

Comment: The cliff edge is "looking down into the valley".

Comment: I read that sentence to mean the implied viewer is looking down into the valley (from the cliff's edge), but it's possible that it's the cliff's edge looking down into the valley

Comment: @KannE  I added the entire paragraph.

Comment: it's still ambiguous and poorly written

Comment: I think it's pretty clearly the cliff edge that is looking down into the valley, but you could argue it's ambiguous. Both interpretations would be grammatically correct.

Comment: // - a cliff edge, perhaps, typically looking down into a valley.// With the commas, it could be interpreted as linking to the viewer; if comma wasn't there, it would surely link to the cliff alone.

Comment: Looking over a valley is also a nice place for a vantage point.

Comment: What is the source of this quote? I cannot find the entire quotation 'as is' anywhere, but parts of it can be found scattered around the Innernette. The beginning of the quote is often attributed to a Denis Dutton.

Answer (score 1):

According to [www.merrian-webster.com/dictionary/look](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/look) we see within the section  **intransitive verb**, (definition 3) "look" can be something that an inanimate object can do. With that I say that the cliff is looking down...

Comment: I agree with that, and it's even more true of the related word [overlook](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/overlook). Both 'look' and 'overlook' are used for natural features and ruins which will only occasionally have a person, or even an animal or bird, using their eyes from that place.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence as it stands *a cliff edge, perhaps, typically looking down into a valley* is in apposition to "some desirable vantage point". And thus, expanded:

> In fact, most landscape representation in the history of painting places the implied viewer at some desirable vantage point **, for example,** a cliff edge, perhaps, **that** typically **is** looking down into a valley.

*at some desirable vantage point, for example, a cliff edge, perhaps, typically looking down into a valley.* is an adjectival phrase modifying "viewer".

Comment: That's one legitimate analysis.

Comment: Hm, someone seems to have disagreed. I wish they'd explain their thinking.

Comment: or just *... , typically **one** looking down into a valley*.